# Error in running unit test for Vue webapp

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I am writing a webapp with VueJs, I am trying to setup unit test for it, I got inspired from [vue-mdl](https://github.com/posva/vue-mdl) unit-tests. But the tests are not running properly for my code and I am getting `vm.$el` as `undefined`, so not able to move forward at all.

Here is the component, I am trying to test:

**Confirmation.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        Your order has been confirmed with the following details.
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      data_from_pg: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here is test for it, which fails

**Confirmation.spec.js**

```
import Confirmation from 'src/components/Confirmation'
import { vueTest } from '../../utils'

describe('Confirmation', () => {
  let vm
  let confirmation
  before(() => {
    vm = vueTest(Confirmation)
    console.log('vm.$el ' + vm.$el) => this prints undefined
    confirmation = vm.$el.querySelector('#confirmation') => so this line gives error
    // confirmation = vm.$('#confirmation')
  })

  it('exists', () => {
    confirmation.should.exist
    confirmation.should.be.visible
  })
})
```

**utils.js**

```
export function vueTest (Component) {
  const Class = Vue.extend(Component)
  Class.prototype.$ = function (selector) {
    return this.$el.querySelector(selector)
  }
  Class.prototype.nextTick = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.$nextTick(resolve)
    })
  }

  const vm = new Class({
    replace: false,
    el: 'body'
  })

  return vm
}
```

My complete code is available [here](https://github.com/mimani/vue-example), with all the test config, which I have tried to change many times, but could not figure out how to make it work. Please let me know if you see some error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `vueTest` function in utils is trying to load the Vue instance into the `body` tag:

```
const vm = new Class({
  replace: false,
  el: 'body'
})
return vm
```

The unit tests do not load `index.html` as an entry point into the app, but rather the individual components that you want to test; Therefore, you do not have access to `document` or html elements and the component is never mounted. I'd suggest using [vm.$mount()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount):

> If elementOrSelector argument is not provided, the template will be rendered as an off-document element.

You could change the above lines to something like the following

```
const vm = new Class();
vm.$mount();
return vm;
```

Your tests should now have access to the $el property.